# How does the zombies campaign work in Black ops 2?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

So I'm just getting into the zombies in Black Ops2 and wondering if there is a campaign mode? Is there a set of levels within Tranzit and Die Rise? Is there an end game or ending to the levels? Boss fights? What levels do I play to get the storyline?

Answer (score 2):

Black Ops 2 has [three zombie modes](http://www.callofduty.com/blackops2/features/zombies), with very little resembling a campaign mode.

#### Tranzit

Tranzit is a co-op multiplayer mode similar to some of the maps in Black Ops.  There are some campaign elements in how you unlock areas/equipment by completing tasks, and hints about a back story as to why the world is a zombie filled corpse pile, but in my opinion it doesn't approach anything you'd call a campaign.

#### Survival

Another co-op mode, Survival is more of a straight up Horde made popular by the Gears of War series.  Spoiler alert, you don't survive.

#### Grief

Grief is a new twist of a multiplayer versus/co-op mode.  I haven't personally played this one, but it looks somewhat in the vein of the Left 4 Dead versus multiplayer, with some new Treyarch special sauce.  Two teams face of, and only one will survive.  Campaign elements: slim/none.

Answer (score 0):

So after playing countless hours and combing through websites you can do easter eggs which give you backstory. And some levels have Boss rounds. But no type of endgame.

Although in Mob of The Dead

> You can do an easter egg that gives the level some kind of ending.